# Find all .docx files, add suffix with Bash

Tags: bash, file-rename

I wish to find all .docx files, and append them a string. This is my current code, which has a little bug

```
find -name '*.docx -execdir mv {} {}$string \;
```

Files are renamed, but string is added like this filename.docx_string and not like that `filename_string.docx`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick and descend into the subdirectories.

```
find ./ -name "*.docx" -print | while read i; do mv "$i" `echo "$i" | sed -e 's/\.docx/_stringhere\.docx/'`; done
```

The `sed -e` portion will perform a regex substitution for `.docx`.

Comment: for is not an option, since it doesn't check recursive. My files will be in sub folders. Will check what sed -e ... does tho! Thank you for your replay.

Comment: Edited to accommodate what you are looking for.

Comment: It might be a litter better if you anchor the extension to the end of the string: `'s/\.docx$/_stringhere\.docx/'`. Or you can use this variation on **ghostdog74's** [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468949/find-all-docx-files-add-sufix-with-bash/3469819#3469819): `mv "$i" "${i/%.docx/${string}.docx}"`

Answer (score 0):

Bash 4

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in **/*.docx
do
  echo mv "$file" "${file%.docx}${string}.docx"
done
```